# Is there a possibility to make reference to the line in the lstlisting environment?

Tags: cross-referencing, listings

I was wondering if it is possible to refer to the lines of the code enclosed in `lstlisting` environment rather than just manually write a number of the line I want to describe. I have never met with this feature, is this available?

Answer (score 29):

At page 53 in [the manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) you will find the section *How to reference line numbers* with the following example:

```
\lstset{escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}
\begin{lstlisting}
 for i:=maxint to 0 do begin
   { comment }(*@\label{comment}@*) 
 end;
\end{lstlisting}
Line \ref{comment} shows a comment.
```