# How to make linenumber referencing in lstlisting work with autoref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, listings

This [Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116217/66800) provides an answer to the question how to make line-number referencing work with `lstlisting`. However, if I use `\autoref` it will only return the number and not something like `Line 31`.

Comment: `\autoref` can't provide for any label/counter entity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\autoref` command can't 'know' the ref name for each counter, this has to be provided as a separate macro:

I used the `listings` example by Marco Daniel provided in the Link by the O.P. and found that `listings` uses `lstnumber` as counter, so

```
\newcommand{\lstnumberautorefname}{Line}
```

is the relevant macro name to be defined (i.e. counter name + `autorefname` as suffix.

'Only' the standard counters such as `chapter`, etc, figure, page, table etc. are predefined. For a full list see the `hyperref` manual. Other packages might define additional `\...autorefname` macros.

Please have a look on the `cleveref` package too.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\newcommand{\lstnumberautorefname}{Line}

\begin{document}




\lstset{escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}
\begin{lstlisting}
 for i:=maxint to 0 do begin
   { comment }(*@\label{comment}@*) 
 end;
\end{lstlisting}
\autoref{comment} shows a comment.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The cleverref package looks great but at this point I am afraid to change my hyperref setup to a cleverref setup as I do not know how much work that will be.

Comment: @MrZ: As long as you include `cleveref` later than `hyperref` everything should be alright anyway.